# How to download packages/modules to python 3.6.0

Tags: python, download, directory

I'm trying to download packages and modules to python. I have never used it before and a lot of videos say you need to have a scripts folder which I do not have. Any help?

The programmer says that if you want to install the packages you have to do

```
$ pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

all the packages are inside a `requirements.txt` file but where do I put that and where do I type the code?

Comment: Which package, what modules? If you don't know anything about Python consider [this tutorial](https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/)

Comment: Im trying to download a bot ish program. It has a .py script and i need to download some packages to help it run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use pip, which is a terminal command.

On linux:

```
pip install <packagename>
```

On windows:

```
py -m pip install <packagename>
python -m pip install <packagename> #which one you use depends on your python version
```

Finally, if you are trying to install a package/module that doesn't have a packagename for pip, you generally have to clone the directory from git and run setup.py

```
git clone <git URL>
cd <cloned repository>
python setup.py install
```

After you have installed the python package you can now import it inside a python script.

```
import <packagename>
```

Answer (score 0):

The pip Python module is used to download and manage Python modules.

```
python -m pip install <package name>
```

> The most common usage of pip is to install from the Python Package Index

The Python Package Index, PyPi (https://pypi.python.org/pypi), is a repository of Python packages. The web interface will let you search for packages and download packages directly. The Python package manager, pip, automates the installation of Python packages and their dependencies.

You should be able to run `pip --version` to get the version of pip installed. If pip is not installed, first try to bootstrap pip from the standard library `python -m ensurepip --default-pip`.

If that fails too, you can download the get-pip.py utility script (https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and run it using `python get-pip.py`.

For more information, take a look at https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/. Along with the information above, it contains a much more detailed explanation of Python package installation and best practices.